# Implement Chat Application through UDP (User Datagram Protocol)?

Tags: visual-c++

Hi I want to implement chat application through UDP in Vc++.net can anyone help me ?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Dou you want to hire someone or do you have a technical questions?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199088/udp-chat-server-in-c) post will help you.

Comment: -1 I feel that the question is too broad.

Comment: Ok Belinda Before asking Next time I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though boost is not the silver bullet, boost asio does have a [client - server - chat example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.chat). This specific example does use tcp though, but it's not difficult to modify it to use udp. There are many other useful examples, such as the [echo which features some UDP examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.echo).

IMO boost-asio is a really well-structured and useful library to write any networking code in.

OTOH boost including asio isn't necessary the easiest library to learn...